# Table name for assignment file path in moodle

Tags: moodle

I attached the file for assignment in moodle and submitted. The assignment file path stored in which table in moodle database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be trying to access Moodle files via the database - use the [Files API](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/File_API) to access them.

If you are interested in finding out how the internals of the Files API work, then you can find more details on the relevant [Moodle docs page](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/File_API_internals). But, you should still avoid accessing the mdl_files database table directly.

Comment: Thanks for your update. actually i tried to get file path for assignment because i have to move the details to another database for my application purpose. That's why i tried like this.